# Makefile: no target error even when target and dependency exist

Tags: bash, makefile

My makefile:

```
./corpus/%.spacy : ./assets/%.json
     python3 ./scripts/convert.py $< $@
```

Two questions:

1. Even if A.spacy and A.json exist and A.json is updated more recently than A.spacy, I get the following output.

   ```
   $ make
   $ make: *** No targets.  Stop.
   ```
2. What to add to have it make A.spacy if only A.json exists? I tried the below code, which didn't work and I feel I'm not fully understanding targets and dependencies in makefiles.

   ```
   convert : ./corpus/%.spacy
        python3 ./scripts/convert.py $(./scripts/$*.json) $<

    ./corpus/%.spacy: ./assets/%.json
       echo $?
   ```

Didn't work as in gave the following output

```
$ make convert
$ make: *** No rule to make target `corpus/%.spacy', needed by `convert'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that declaring a pattern rule will cause make to go spelunking your directory looking for all possible ways to use that pattern, as if it were a wildcard or something akin to `ls *.spacy`.

That's not what a pattern rule is.

A pattern rule is a *template* that make *can* apply **if** it wants to build a given target and it doesn't know how to build that target.

If you have the above makefile it just tells make "hey, if you happened to want to create a target that matches the pattern `./corpus/%.spacy` then here's a way to do it".  If you type `make` with no arguments, then you haven't told make that you want to build anything so it won't use your pattern rule.

If you type:

```
$ make ./corpus/A.spacy
```

*now* you've told make you want to actually build something (`./corpus/A.spacy`), so now make will try to build that thing, and it will see your pattern rule and it will try to use it.

As for the other, this:

```
convert : ./corpus/%.spacy
        python3 ./scripts/convert.py $(./scripts/$*.json) $<
```

is not a pattern rule.  A pattern rule must have a pattern character (`%`) in the *target*; this is defining a target `convert` that depends on a file named, explicitly, `./corpus/%.spacy` of which you don't have any file with that name, so you get that error.

You didn't actually describe what you wanted to do, but I *think* maybe you want to do something like this:

```
# Find all the .json files
JSONS := $(wildcard ./assets/*.json)

# Now figure out all the output files we want
SPACYS := $(patsubst ./assets/%.json,./corpus/%.spacy,$(JSONS))

# Now create a target that depends on the stuff we want to create
all: $(SPACYS)

# And here's a pattern that tells make how to create ONE spacy file:
./corpus/%.spacy : ./assets/%.json
        python3 ./scripts/convert.py $< $@
```

Comment: Thank you. The line is `SPACYS := $(patsubst ./assets/%.json, ./corpus/%.spacy, $(JSONS)). Very helpful.